# Replace JavaScript's function keyword

Tags: javascript, function, declaration, keyword

Is it possible to replace the `function` keyword to something smaller like `void`, `sub` etc ?

I've seen it being used in libraries like these two:

- [Sweet.Js](http://sweetjs.org/)
- [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/)

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: In JavaScript, it's not. The libraries you posted are things you run text through, that generates JavaScript. The code you write with them isn't necessarily JavaScript

Comment: yes, as you said yourself, `sweetjs`, etc do it. but the browser won't understand it.

Comment: @akonsu But is it possible to make one myself?

Comment: @user1490835 Writing a smaller keyword than `function`

Comment: you can implement your own language yes. but the browsers would still only understand javascript. you would need to write a plugin or something like that for it to work in a browser.

Comment: @akonsu Ok, so I can't write a shorthand like for example getElementById and so on?

Comment: Seriously. "function" is only 8 characters. It's not going to exactly wear out the keyboard.

Comment: for `getElementById` you can write your own wrapper and install it on the prototype of the `HTMLElement` (or wherever it is defined) and use it. it is different than changing a language keyword.

Comment: @Juhana Well, the creator of JavaScript has stated that he regrets the keyword function (he would have made a shorter one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "typescript" for these things. It is a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript. So it is javascript with lots of new features. It is created by Microsoft.

[Typescript Official Webpage](http://www.typescriptlang.org/)

Comment: I know that I can use that, but I wanted to do it in plain JavaScript. Apparently, that is not possible.

Comment: Yes, not possible. You must use compiler (typescript, coffeescript, sweetjs or something) to work with these.

Comment: I accepted your answer. I was a bit confused, thanks for clearing up :)